# Referencing a type parameter as a function parameter in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to make an "integer mod p" type in Julia.  (I'm sure there's already a package for this, it's just a personal exercise.)

```
type Intp{p}
    v::Int8
end

function add(a::Intp{p},b::Intp{p})
    return Intp{p}((a.v + b.v) % p)
    end
```

I'm getting an error when defining add that says p is not defined.  How do I reference p from inside add?

(Note: I could do something like

```
type Intp
    v::Int8
    p
end

function add(a::Intp,b::Intp)
    return Intp((a.v + b.v) % a.p,p)
    end
```

but this would require that p be stored with every single number.  I feel like this would be inefficient, and I have my mind on generalizations where it would be really inefficient.  I would rather p just be specified once, for the type, and referenced in functions that take things of that type as arguments.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first example is very close, but you need to include `{p}` between the method name and the signature like this:

```
function add{p}(a::Intp{p},b::Intp{p})
    return Intp{p}((a.v + b.v) % p)
end
```

Otherwise, you are writing a method for a pair of `Intp{p}` values where `p` is whatever the current specific value of `p` may be – which, in your case, happens to be no value at all, hence the error message. So the general signature of a Julia method is:

1. method name
2. type parameters in `{ }` (optional)
3. arguments in `( )`

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I like your language.

Comment: Recent versions of Julia no longer accept this syntax. Instead, a `where` clause _after_ the closing parenthesis of the function argument list provides access to the type parameter in the function body: `function add(a::Intp{p},b::Intp{p}) where {p}` Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940710/5058794 provides additional information about this syntax change.