# How to use a vector as a type parameter in Julia

Tags: julia

This is similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320124/referencing-a-type-parameter-as-a-function-parameter-in-julia), but a bit more complicated.

Before I was defining a type with an associated integer as a parameter, Intp{p}.  Now I would like to define a type using a vector as a parameter.

The following is the closest I can write to what I want:

```
type Extp{g::Vector{T}}
     c::Vector{T}
end
```

In other words, Extp should be defined with respect to a Vector, g, and I want the contents, c, to be another Vector, whose entries should be the of the same type as the entries of g.

Well, this does not work.

Problem 1: I don't think I can use :: in the type parameter.

Problem 2: I could work around that by making the types of g and c arbitary and just making sure the types in the vectors match up in the constructor.  But, even if I completely take everything out and use

```
type Extp{g}
     c
end
```

it still doesn't seem to like this.  When I try to use it the way I want to,

> julia> Extp{[1,1,1]}([0,0,1])
>
> ERROR: type: apply_type: in Extp, expected Type{T<:Top}, got Array{Int64,1}

So, does Julia just not like particular Vectors being associated with types?  Does what I'm trying to do only work with integers, like in my Intp question?

EDIT: In the documentation I see that type parameters "can be any type at all (or an integer, actually, although here it’s clearly used as a type)."  Does that mean that what I'm asking is impossible, and that that *only* types and integers work for Type parameters?  If so, why? (what makes integers special over other types in Julia in this way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [relevant quote](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/types/#types):

> Both abstract and concrete types can be parameterized by other types
>   and by certain other values (currently integers, symbols, bools, and
>   tuples thereof).

So, your EDIT is correct. Widening this has come up on the Julia issues page (e.g., [#5102](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5102) and [#6081](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6081) were two related issues I found with some discussion), so this may change in the future - I'm guessing not in `v0.4` though. It'd have to be an immutable type really to make any sense, so not `Vector`. I'm not sure I understand your application, but would a `Tuple` work?

Comment: This is working towards constructing polynomial quotient rings.  The existing Vector{T} is sufficient to represent polynomials with coefficients in an arbitrary type.  But, given a polynomial g(X) (represented as a vector), I would like to make a type where other polynomials are automatically reduced modulo g(X).  The issue is that I want to make leave T arbitrary so that, for example, I can make polynomials of polynomials mod g(X), modulo a polynomial h(X) of polynomials modulo g(X).

Comment: So, if you know abstract algebra, I am extending to GF(q) = GF(p)[x]/(g(x)), then extending to GF(q)[X]/(h(X)) = (GF(p)[x]/(g(x)))[X]/(h(X)).  It's OK for g(x) and h(X) to be immutable, but h(X) has coefficients which are not immutable.  It would have to be a tuple of vectors.

Answer (score 5):

In Julia 0.4, you can use any "bitstype" as a parameter of a type. However, a vector is not a bitstype, so this is not going to work. The closest analog is to use a tuple: for example, `(3.2, 1.5)` is a perfectly valid type parameter.

In a sense vectors (or any mutable object) are antithetical to types, which cannot change at runtime.

Comment: Can they be tuples of user defined types?  I tried making a type T{Tuple}, and T{(1,2,3)} initialized, but T{(Intp{2}(1),Intp{2}(0)} did not (where Intp{p} is an immutable Intp{p} <: Integer that I defined)